# How to register/instantiate sideNav() from dynamically added button

Tags: jquery, materialize

I'm using Materializecss framework. I have a sideNav that opens from the right hand side of the screen.

Users will most often open it from a menu which sits at the top of the page and is generated on page load. Clicking any of these items works fine to open the sideNav.

The issue arises when I load a button dynamically that should also open the right sideNav to do it's intended actions.

When clicking on this dynamically added all the required processing happens (collecting data, posting to ajax etc), but the sideNav never opens.

I thought maybe it was todo with initializing the button after adding it dynamically.

So I took the materializecss code for initializing the right sidebar:

```
$('.button-collapse-right').sideNav({
    menuWidth: getPanelWidth(), // Default is 240
    edge: 'right', // Choose the horizontal origin
    closeOnClick: false // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
});
```

And moved it into a separate function:

```
initializeSideNavRight = function(btnObj) {
    $(btnObj).sideNav({
        menuWidth: getPanelWidth(), // Default is 240
        edge: 'right', // Choose the horizontal origin
        closeOnClick: false // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
    });
};
```

and then right after generating and adding the btn to the DOM I call this function (like below):

```
    var primaryBtn = '<a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary '+btnClass+' pull-right bulk-action" data-action="'+action+'" data-activates="'+activates+'">'+btnText+'</a>';
    var btnWrapper = $('#bulk-action-button');
    btnWrapper.html(primaryBtn);
    $('#bulk-action-container').removeClass('hide');
    var btn = btnWrapper.find('.button-collapse-right');
    initializeSideNavRight(btn);
```

The problem is, if I do this, then the sideNav opens fine, but none of the other stuff fires. No idea why that happens.

This is the main function that fires all the data collecting and ajax page request:

```
$(document).on('click', '.action-panel-button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Action panel fired');
    processActionPanel(this);
});
```

Works fine if I don't run initializeSideNavRight(), but doesn't once I do.

I also tried programmatically opening the sideNav using this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-collapse-right', function(e) {
    console.log('Registered a click for right sideNav');
    $(this).sideNav('show');    
});
```

But that creates an infinite loop, and I am missing why that happens.

As you can see I'm a bit lost, can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution offered by @ville here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26839190/1309710

By swapping the click eventhandler to mouseup on my '.action-panel-button', all functions can be fired once the button is initialized after being added to the DOM.