# JQuery cancel others event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a buton in my code and I need stop others event clicks on this button, but I need the other events still binded.

The code:

```
var cancel = true;

$("#btn").on("click", function(ev) { 
    console.log("FIRST CLICK");
});

$("#btn").on("click", function(ev) { 
    console.log("SECOND CLICK");
    if(cancel) {
       --- cancel first click---
    }
});
```

The usage:

```
cancel = true;
$("#btn").click();
cancel = false;
$("#btn").click();
```

Expected output:

```
SECOND CLICK

FIRST CLICK
SECOND CLICK
```

I already try

```
ev.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
ev.stopPropagation();
ev.preventDefault(); 
return false;
```

but any of this work, how I stop all other click events binded without unbind?

Comment: If the first one is attached first, there is nothing you can really do.... You can bind mousedown instead of click and stop it. Or you can hook up the other events to use eventDelegation... or you can override how jQuery adds events so you can bind your first.

Comment: i don´t understand what you want to achieve? what will happen within your events? do you want that it should not be possible to click button 1 while the action of button 2 is actually in progress? it also makes no sense to bind the click event twice to the same id. use a switch block or if/else instead.

Comment: Do you want to cancel or is it possible to remove the other event handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .off jquery method is the way to go i think

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(ev) { 
console.log("FIRST CLICK");
});

$("#btn").on("mousedown", function(ev) { 
console.log("SECOND CLICK");
--- cancel first click---
$("#btn").off('click');
$("#btn").text("Anything you want to do");
// then if you need to rebind you can do 
$("#btn").on("click", function(ev) { 
console.log("FIRST CLICK");
});
});
```

So you unbind it run the code rebind it. But i think the answer to your problem is that `$(function(){

```
var cancel= 'true';
$("#btn").on("click",function(e){
             if(cancel == 'true'){
    cancel = 'false';
}else{
    cancel = 'true';
}
             });

});
```

Sorry for the indentation but this will switch cancel to on/off
I think that was the goal intended. When you click on the button it will switch for false to true or true to false.

Comment: i like that one :) But I do not understand what he really wants to achieve

Comment: I think the first code handles something, but if the second one can be triggered he has to overwrite it

Comment: Almost it, but this unbind other clicks

Comment: than you should read this [In JS, you don't really have control over what order the event handlers are called](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17352923/3877877)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to carefully mind the *order* that events are bound. By binding the more important click first, we can `stopImmediatePropagation()` to cancel any subsequent bindings.

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  console.log("Reversed second click");
});
$("#btn").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Reversed first click");
});
```

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("First click");
});
$("#btn").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  console.log("Second click");
});

$("#btn2").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  console.log("Reversed second click");
});
$("#btn2").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Reversed first click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">
  Something
</button>
<button id="btn2">
  Reversed Order
</button>
```