# How to trigger another function when i click on element with onclick atribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have small question.
How to trigger another function when I click on element with **onclick="show_order_info(numbers);"**
Onclick atributes have random numbers, il try regex...

I need the standard function to be executed when I clicked and then mine function, I don't have access to the original js, I just want to improve functional for me

But problem is *Uncaught ReferenceError: show_order_info is not defined*

```js
$('.redbutton').on('click', /show_order_info\(\d+\)\;/).innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show_order_info(2588093);" class="redbutton" style=""><img src="/images/admin/pdf_ico.png" style="vertical-align: initial; height: 16px; width: 16px">Show Order</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="printPdf(&quot;/ajax_partner_orderinfo?uoid=2588093&amp;print=1&quot;)" class="redbutton"><img src="/images/admin/pdf_ico.png" style="vertical-align: initial; height: 16px; width: 16px">Print Order</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show_order_info(2797617);" class="redbutton" style=""><img src="/images/admin/pdf_ico.png" style="vertical-align: initial; height: 16px; width: 16px">Show Order</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="printPdf(&quot;/ajax_partner_orderinfo?uoid=2797617&amp;print=1&quot;)" class="redbutton"><img src="/images/admin/pdf_ico.png" style="vertical-align: initial; height: 16px; width: 16px">Print Order</a>
```

Comment: I believe this post will help you find a suitable answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352104/multiple-js-event-handlers-on-single-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not execute on click, you execute the regex as a comma delimited statement

Perhaps you mean

```js
const yourFunction = but => but.textContent = "you clicked me";
const show_order_info = order => console.log(order)
const printPdf = url => console.log(url)

$('.redbutton').each(function() {
//  const click = this.onclick.toString().match(/\{\s+?(.*?)\s+?\}/)[1];
    const click = this.onclick;
    this.onclick=null;
  console.log(click)
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    yourFunction(this)
    click()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show_order_info(2588093);" class="redbutton" style=""><img src="/images/admin/pdf_ico.png" style="vertical-align: initial; height: 16px; width: 16px">Show Order</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="printPdf(&quot;/ajax_partner_orderinfo?uoid=2588093&amp;print=1&quot;)" class="redbutton"><img src="/images/admin/pdf_ico.png" style="vertical-align: initial; height: 16px; width: 16px">Print Order</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show_order_info(2797617);" class="redbutton" style=""><img src="/images/admin/pdf_ico.png" style="vertical-align: initial; height: 16px; width: 16px">Show Order</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="printPdf(&quot;/ajax_partner_orderinfo?uoid=2797617&amp;print=1&quot;)" class="redbutton"><img src="/images/admin/pdf_ico.png" style="vertical-align: initial; height: 16px; width: 16px">Print Order</a>
```